# Modifying the parent of an instantiated prefab throws error

Tags: unity-game-engine

*Before anything, I have looked around, as this seems to be a common error and quite well documented. I know that the error occurs when trying to modify the transform of a prefab. I do not think I am doing that.*

I have the following script attached to a prefab object - it's a card for a card game. The script is to drag and drop the card.

It works very well as long as the card is instantiated before I play the game ; if I instantiate it in game and try to move it, I get the following error :

`Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption`

```
public class CardDrag : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    // HANDLES DRAG OF CARDS

    private Transform originalParent; // saving the original parent
    private Card card; // Card is a scriptable object, card holds data
    private Transform canvas; // a reference to the main canvas

    public void SetCanvas(Transform setCanvas)
    {
        canvas = setCanvas;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        originalParent = transform.parent;
        transform.SetParent(canvas); // WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        gameObject.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        gameObject.transform.SetParent(originalParent);
    }
}
```

The script that handles cards in hand is the following one ; it instantiates the cards that are to be dragged in the game.

```
public class HandManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // MANAGES GENERAL BEHAVIOURS FOR THE HAND OF CARDS

    public GameObject cardPrefab; // a prefab reference to a card
    public Transform canvas; // a reference to the main UI canvas
    public Hand availableCards; // another scriptable object, which holds a "public List<Card> cards;"

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (Card card in availableCards.cards)
        {
            SetUpCard(card);
        }
    }

    private void SetUpCard(Card cardData)
    {
        GameObject newCard= Instantiate(cardPrefab, transform); // instantiating new card
        newCard.GetComponent<CardManager>().SetCardData(cardData); // setting the card's data
        newCard.GetComponent<CardDrag>().SetCanvas(canvas);
    }
}
```

I have been looking this error up, and it is always said that the problem occurs when attempting to change a prefab's parent instead of a prefab's *instance*'s parents.

I do not see the problem though, since I believe I'm instantiating the cards properly in the `SetUpCard()` function ; and the script that manages the dragging is attached to that instance.

Does anyone know and can explain to me why even though `CardDrag` is attached to the prefab, `transform` refers to the Prefab and not to the Instance ?

EDIT : here's the error stack as seen in the editor :

```
Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a Prefab Asset is disabled to prevent data corruption (GameObject: 'Card(Clone)').
UnityEngine.Transform:SetParent(Transform, Boolean)
CardDrag:OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData) (at 
Assets/_Scripts/UI/CardDrag.cs:37)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the error? Which class and line does it occur, this might give clues as to which of your objects is being used incorrectly.

Comment: @CaTs Edited the question with the info.

Comment: Someone answered but deleted their answer... 
Turns out the error message says that my canvas was the problem ; and indeed it was : I had messed up the reference in the editor for some reason...

Comment: Are you sure the public transform canvas you dropped into the script is the one in the scene and not the prefab in your assets folder? I'm asking because there is no picture of the Inspector to see what you dragged into the public slot of the HandManager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when attempting to change a prefab's parent instead of a prefab's instance's parents.

The error message is a bit unclarity, it means the argument of `SetParent` is a transform from a prefab, so here the argument `canvas` is a wrong transform, check your code on the method `SetCanvas` or the reference in `HandManager`.

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered but deleted, so I'm answering again for anyone having my problem in the future and to set the question as answered.

Turns out the error message is saying that the `canvas` is the problem, and indeed I had messed up the reference in the editor.

Thanks mysterious person !

Comment: Sorry, I click the delete link by accident.